# plsql show only 1 date, view

Tags: sql, oracle, view

In my View the description field is filled with a date field, but there are like seven times the same datefield but with different order_keys (thats how it supposed to be). How can i make the view only show always one of the date fields?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW CCI.VW_TA04_BAG_5B
(
   ID,
   LIST_DESCRIPTION,
   ORDER_KEY
)
AS
   SELECT 
          distinct LPAD (bac.bag_id, 4, '0') || LPAD (bac.ID, 4, '0'),
          '      ' || bar.SCORE_RULE_VALID_TO,
          LPAD (bac.order_key, 4, '0')  || LPAD (bar.order_key, 4, '0')
     FROM BART_CATEGORIES bac,
          BART_CATEGORIES_LAE bacl,
          BART_CATEGORY_rules bar
    WHERE     bacl.lae_id = pkg_process.language
          AND (bar.BAC_ID = bac.id)
          AND Bacl.BAC_ID = bac.id
          AND bar.SCORE_RULE_VALID_TO IS NOT NULL
    order by 3
```

The output looks like this:

```
ID                Description order key
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020168
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020169
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020170
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020171
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020172
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020173
00010001          20-MAR-17 00020174
00010001          08-MAR-17 00020175
00010001          08-MAR-17 00020176
00010001          08-MAR-17 00020177
00010001          08-MAR-17 00020178
00010001          08-MAR-17 00020179
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I know you've got an ORDER BY in your view but you can't prevent a user applying their own sort, and there where is your "first" date?

Comment: So what should the output look like? You're showing the order key, so are you saying you only want to show the description against some of them (which?) and null against the rest; or that you only want to show one order key for each description (again, which one?); or you want to do a listagg of the keys? Or something else?

Comment: Iam using this view for list in forms, where i have an history tab, and the user first should choose the id (other list), and then a date, but i don't need in my list ten times the same date field, i need it only ones.

Comment: Sounds the query/view *does* need that, and your front end should hide any duplicates you don't want to show. This seems to be a display issue, not a query issue?

Comment: That's right it is a display issue, but how can i solve it in the view?

Comment: You can't. You need to solve it in the Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after one row per id and list_description, here's one way you could do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW CCI.VW_TA04_BAG_5B
  (ID,
   LIST_DESCRIPTION,
   ORDER_KEY)
AS
SELECT ID,
       list_desciption,
       MAX(order_key) order_key
FROM   (SELECT lpad(bac.bag_id, 4, '0') || lpad(bac.id, 4, '0') id,
               '      ' || bar.score_rule_valid_to list_description,
               lpad(bac.order_key, 4, '0') || lpad(bar.order_key, 4, '0') order_key
        FROM   bart_categories bac, bart_categories_lae bacl, bart_category_rules bar
        WHERE  bacl.lae_id = pkg_process.language
        AND    (bar.bac_id = bac.id)
        AND    bacl.bac_id = bac.id
        AND    bar.score_rule_valid_to IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ID,
         list_description
ORDER BY order_key;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted, sorry if i asked not precicse enough

Comment: It was good that you provided the view and the output it currently produces. However, it would have helped you get a faster answer if you had included the output you wanted to get as well. Please bear that in mind when you ask future questions *{:-)